# How do I create an EJB Timer service and deploy it to a weblogic 9.2 server running in eclipse?

Tags: java, timer, ejb-2.x, weblogic9.x

After trawling the internet for 2 days now I'm am struggling to find any good 
running examples of the EJB timer service running on weblogic. Is there anyone out there that can at least point me in the right direction? Any help will be greatly appreciated

I currently have weblogic installed and running in eclipse and some very basic timer service code(java files only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only answer then must be: Move to quartz!

EDIT: after using quartz in a large webapp I am very pleased with the results!

If interested check out: [Quartz Spring Doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/scheduling.html) and also [Official open Symphony website](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)

Quartz provides a great set of feature's for simple timers up to complex cron timers. And separates jobs, schedules and triggers making it very configurable.